# Changing the lat/long coordinates of a data layer to match the satellite image features manually

Tags: qgis

I have a satellite image data of

1. weddell sea and a
2. ice thickness data file from an Airbourne laser scanner,

both having spatial data. However, these two data are from different dates and therefore, due to ice floe movements, the thickness layer doesn't exactly align on the thickest or thinnest places.

So, I would like to know if there is any way to manually move this data layer of thickness ton top of the satellite image to match it with the features on the image.

As you can see in the image attached, the yellow dotted part of the line is higher thickness and should be on top of the bright white floe of ice. So, I need help in a way to move this up manually.

I could maybe edit the coordinate (lat/long) of the thickness data file, like a trial and error, but problem is I don't know how.

[image: These are the satellite image and thickness data]

Comment: You can move the points using [Affine transform](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaffinetransform)